# Automapper Compile Mappings

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

We use automapper with ASP.NET Core 2.0.

We like to create a mapping configuration once, which will be used from each mapper. We create a mapper per request that we will not have problems because I read once automapper is not thread safe.

We like to precompile the mappingconfiguration at application startup (See in Code MapperConfigruation.CompileMappings();

If I measure the time how long the mapping takes, i see that the first mapping need more time than the other mappings. Is there a reason for that or do I have bug?

**Code**

***In ConfigureService of Startup class:***

```
 services.AddSingleton<MyMapperConfiguration>();
 services.AddScoped<IObjectMapper, MyMapper>();
```

***Mapperconfiguration***

```
public class MyMapperConfiguration
    {
        public MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; private set; }

        public MappingDefinition MappingDefinition { get; }

        public MapperConfiguration(IOptions<MappingDefinition> mappings)
        {
            // MappingDefinitions hold some information where to search mappings  
            MappingDefinition = mappings.Value;
        }


        public void Configure()
        {
            List<Type> mappingDefinitionClasses = new List<Type>();

             // Search Types with special attribute and add it to the typelist

            MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfiles(mappingDefinitionClasses.ToArray());
            });            
            MapperConfiguration.CompileMappings(); // <-- THIS SHOULD COMPILE THE MAPPING I THNIK?!

        }
```

`

***Mapper***

```
 public class MyMapper : IObjectMapper
    {      
        public IMapper Mapper { get; }

        public Mapper(MapperConfiguration mappingConfiguration)
        {           
            Mapper = mappingConfiguration.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        }

        public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source);
        }
    }
```

***IObjectMapper:***

```
   public interface IObjectMapper
    {        
        TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source);        
    }
```

***Measure time inside a webApi***

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
destObj = _mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(sourceObj);
sw.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine($"Duration of mapping: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

In the Configruate methode of Startup I also get an instance of the mapping configuration and call Configure() that this instance lifes.

Comment: You should look at the extensions package to ASP.NET Core for AutoMapper: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection that makes all this much easier to set up.

Comment: We do not like to have a direct dependeny to automapper. It should be possible to exchange the mapper implementantion

Comment: What? Why? That'll be a tooooon of work without much benefit. If you want to change mapper implementations, don't abstract, just learn regex.

Comment: Regex and mapping?

Comment: Main goal it to have te possibility to exchange the mapper implementation on one place.

Comment: That's a lot of work for something that's really not that hard to do in practice (replace mapper).

Comment: @JimmyBogard: It's not so much work. I do not understand what you mean. I'm using the mapper maybe in 100 different places in my code. In the case I like to replace the automapper with another mapper I have to change this on all 100 places. With this solution I replace it on one place.

Comment: Having replaced ORMs many times, abstracting things doesn't actually make it easier. Your configuration will be different for one, so that's why I don't bother abstracting things. It doesn't actually make it easier to migrate, it makes it harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AM is thread safe. The mapper itself is not expensive, you can share it or not. It does allocate a few things, so it's cheaper to share it if you can. CompileMappings changed a bit, so upgrade to the latest. But other than that, it's probably the JIT compiler you're seeing. Until the mapping is executed, the code doesn't get compiled. CompileMappings just compiles an expression to IL. The JIT compiles IL to machine code. You can profile and verify what happens.